Draw a colored point cloud from csv file
I have a 150000 rows CSV file with x, y, z coordinates and a category column (with values "A", "B", or "C") for each point. I want to create a point cloud visualization in Blender, where each point is colored based on its category. Plus I also want to be able to repaint these points directly in the Blender editor. Is it somewhat possible whit that many vertex? Util now I've only been able to make the points but not color them.
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for row in reader:
    # Parse coordinates
    x = float(row['x'])
    y = float(row['y'])
    z = float(row['z'])
    
    # Parse category
    category = row['category']
    
    # Add point to the vertices list
    vertices.append((x, y, z))
    
    # Add category to the categories list
    categories.append(category)

thats the way im going through the csv, anything can help, thanks

Hello and welcome. Vertices themselves cannot be colored but you can easily place (or instantiate) small spherical mesh objects on each point to which you can assign different colors.
